# Pulling in value associated with a date that closest to another date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables.  The first is a list of individuals (IDs) and a transaction date.  The second is a customer history table which contains a snapshot of customer data over time.  I'm interested in pulling in the membership flag for the run date that is closest to but BEFORE the transaction date.

*** EDIT:**  I tried using TOP 1, and rank over/partition... but they take too long to run. I don't have the right to create an index on the table.  This is the query that got me what I need:

```
SELECT  t1.*, t2.RunDate, t2.CST_ISMEMBER 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
   ON t1.ID=t2.ID
   AND t2.RunDate = 
            (SELECT MAX(t2b.RunDate) 
            FROM table2 t2b  
            WHERE t2b.ID=t2.ID AND t1.TransDate >= t2b.RunDate)
```

**MORE EDITS *** I found that for approx 9K individuals from Table 1, the Rundate in Table 2 occurs AFTER the transaction date.  So now I need to find the date CLOSEST  to (before or after) the transaction. Struggling to find a datediff solution that doesn't involve rank over/partition or top 1 giving my lack of index issue.  I've had to kill the query after 5 minutes so I don't get yelled at by IT ;-)
These are the indexes available on table 2 which is the largest.

[image]

```
    TABLE 1 
ID   TransDate 
1    8/20/13
2    9/5/14

TABLE 2
ID   RunDate      IsMember
1    6/30/2010    Y
1    7/11/2012    N
1    7/30/2013    N
1    8/15/2013    Y
2    9/1/2014     Y
2    9/10/2014    N
```

Desired result:

```
ID  TransDate   IsMember
1   8/20/13     N
2   9/5/14      Y
```

What is the best way to approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @kiki1113 . . . You should edit  your question with the indexes that ARE available on the table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - updated to include indexes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correlated subquery is a simple method.  Here is what the code looks like:

```
select t1.*,
       (select top (1) t2.ismember
        from table2 t2
        where t2.id = t1.id and t2.rundate < t1.transdate
        order by t2.rundate desc
       ) as ismember
from table1 t1;
```

For performance you want an index on `table2(id, rundate, ismember)`.

EDIT:

You have lousy indexes for this.  How this history table could not have an index on `id` is very strange.  Here is an entirely different approach that uses window functions.

```
with t as (
      select id, transdate as dte, null as ismember, 1 as which
      from table1
      union all
      select id, rundate, ismember, 2
      from table2
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(ismember) over (partition by id order by dte, which desc) as ismember
      from t
     ) t
where which = 1;
```

I suspect that the `lag()` over the unioned data will be faster than any attempt to fix the first method.  However, the first would be much faster with the appropriate index.

Comment: Thank you - this appears to be working; however, it's taking quite a long time to process.  For reference,table 1 has 8,932 rows table 2 has 16,806,807.  Is there a way to improve upon the time it takes to run or is it just the nature of having sunch a large table 2 for it to run through?

Comment: @kiki1113 . .  The outer table reference should be `table1` rather than `table2` (that was a typo).  I also added information on indexing and fixed the syntax for SQL Server.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff, unfortunately I don't have rights to create the index.  I found an alternative that worked using a subquery that selects that MAX run date where the IDs match and the transaction date is >= run date... but I just found out that for 9K records, the record in the t2 was created AFTER the transaction date... so now I need to revise.  Editing above for more detail.

Comment: Thank you - this was much faster and got me to what I need.  I agree with you on the index.  Will have to get w/ IT to find out why that is.

Comment: Not sure how the "top 1" version would've taken since I killed it after 7 minutes.  The second alternative you provided ran in less than 30 second :-)  Thank you!